# Upgrading HP P4000 networking

Tags: lefthand

Our dealer currently has a killer deal on [HP LeftHand P4000 starter kits](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/me/en/sm/WF06b/12169-304616-3930449-3930449-3930449-4118659-4118707.html?dnr=1) and we're considering purchasing one or two of them; however each chassis only has 2x 1GbE ethernet. This seems a bit light on to me. HP don't seem to [offer anything but 10GbE](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/uk/en/sm/WF17a/A1-329290-3320517-3320518-3320518-3936288.html) upgrades.

Is it possible to install a 4-Port PCI-e NIC into these chassis and have it work with the software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may work with the software, but due to the way bonding works with LeftHand units, you're not going to see more than 1-Gigabit per LUN anyway. What do you *think* you need in terms of storage networking? If you care about per-LUN throughput, 10GbE is the right solution.

Since you'll be doing iSCSI MPIO, it's not as though you'd get a bigger bonded link by adding more interfaces. LeftHand scales by adding nodes.

Comment: Basically I know that the unit can pump out way more than the 1Gbps limit, and I was hoping to find a way to tap into additional bandwidth in the unit should we saturate the links it comes with. I guess I'm used to Dell hardware that has more network ports than you can poke a stick at.

Comment: 10GbE ;) Make the jump!

Comment: Heh. We have some 10Gb equallogic gear, this budget doesn't quite extend that far though.